# Replace the last digit (x + 1) of the link every 3 hours

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace the last digit (x + 1) of the link every 3 hours and automatically.
is it possible? I would be happy to answer quickly.
Thanks.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/id=10855**9**" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Javascript supports timed events. You can Google it.

Comment: There are three questions here: how to edit the `src` of an `iframe` on the page, how to increment a number at the end of a URL, and how to run code on a page every three hours. Which one do you need help with? If you already know some of them, edit your question to include your solution for that functionality. If you don't know any of them, asking separate questions for each will make it easier to get answers.

Comment: who is leaving the page open for 3 hours to make this relevant?...are you sure you are not looking for server side code instead that generates the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using some regEx to grab the value from the src directly. setInterval will run the code every x milliseconds (could be 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3 for 3 hours)

```js
var timeInterval = 1000; //value in ms you want the code to run

setInterval(function(){
  var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
  var prev = frame.src.match(/.*?\*\*(\d*)\*\*/)[1];
  var next = (+prev) + 1;
  frame.src = frame.src.replace(/\*\*(\d*)\*\*/, "**"+next+"**");
  console.log(frame.src);
}, timeInterval);
```

```html
<iframe id='frame' src="https://www.example.com/id=10855**9**" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

without the asterisks

```js
var timeInterval = 1000; //value in ms you want the code to run

setInterval(function(){
  var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
  var prev = frame.src.match(/.*?=(\d*)/)[1];
  var next = (+prev) + 1;
  frame.src = frame.src.replace(/id=(\d*)/, "id="+next);
  console.log(frame.src);
}, timeInterval);
```

```html
<iframe id='frame' src="https://www.example.com/id=108559" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can you show me the code without the asterisks?

Comment: @ItaiItai like that? (the second example)

Comment: Now I see it! Excellent!!

Answer (score 0):

to replace the last digit of string you can use `replace` method on the string like

```
var x = "https://www.example.com/id=108559"

x.replace(x.charAt(x.length-1),x.charAt(x.length-1)+1)
```

to repeat it every 3 hours you have 2 options :

- to use setInterval

  ```
  setInterval(function(){
    // your code here
  },1000*60*60*3)
  ```
- or the best choice to use `Worker` to reduce the processing on your main thread

Answer (score 0):

[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) repeatedly calls a function after a given time. To add 1 in the last character you could use `src.slice(0, -1) + (+src[src.length-1]+1)`. So you could do something like:

```
   <iframe src="https://www.example.com/id=10855" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
    <script>


        setInterval(function(){ 
            var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
            var src = iframe[0].getAttribute("src");
            var nsrc = src.slice(0, -1) + (+src[src.length-1]+1);
            console.log(nsrc);
            iframe[0].src=nsrc;

         }, 10800000);//3 hours

        </script>
```

Full example here https://jsfiddle.net/h2q8ub1v/1/

To change last 5 numbers

```
var last = src.slice(src.length -5, src.length)
var nsrc = src.slice(0, -5) + (+last+1);
```

The example here https://jsfiddle.net/h2q8ub1v/13/

Comment: Can the code +1 all five digits? So that when he reaches 10 he will be transferred to the position of dozens.  (xxxxx+1)

Comment: @ItaiItai I've updated the response, to change last 5 numbers jsfiddle.net/h2q8ub1v/13